# Exponential Function of Quaternion - Derivation

Tags: quaternions

The equation for the exponential function of a quaternion $q = a + b i + c j + dk$ is supposed to be $$e^{q} = e^a \left(\cos(\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2})+\frac{(b i + c j + dk)}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}} \sin(\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2})\right)$$

I'm having a difficult time finding a derivation of this formula.  I keep trying to derive it, but I end up getting different results.  Would someone be able to point me to a proof of this formula or do the derivation here?

Note: I also don't understand why some people say $e^q = e^a e^{b i + c j + d k}$. Can you please explain this, too?

Comment: That exponential function is from the quaternions... *to where* ? And how do you **define**, say $\;e^j\;,\;\;e^k\;$ , etc.?

Comment: I think a natural way to extend the exponential function to quaternions would be to use the Taylor series of the exponential over the complex and just extend domain and range to include quaternions.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, perhaps. In the meantime the OP hasn't yet addressed my doubts and I'm not in the mood for guessing posters' intentions. I agree with you, though.

Comment: The exponential function would map the quaternions to the quaternions.

Comment: $e^j=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{j^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n)!} + j \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} =  cos(1) + j sin(1)$

Comment: @Jade196 I would first check that if $e^x:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n/n!$ for $x$ in a normed algebra then $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$. Then $e^{q}=e^ae^{bi}e^{cj}e^{dk}$, which is maybe more comfortable to compute. You have essentially computed already $e^{xr}$, for $x$ real and $r=i,j,k$. $e^{xr}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(xr)^n/n!=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}/(2n)!+r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}/(2n+1)!=\cos(x)+r\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Jade196 We get $e^q=e^a(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))(\cos(c)+j\sin(c))(\cos(d)+k\sin(d))$. Now we open parentheses, use the product table of $i,j,k$, and do some trigonometry.

Comment: @Jade196 Alternatively, we could expand the right-hand side in your formula and check it is equal to the product in the previous comment. Maybe this way is more comfortable because we don't have to synthesize a trigonometric expression, instead it is all about opening brackets of a product of series.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The definition of quaternionic exponential is given by the absolutely convergent series
$$
e^z=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{z^k}{k!}
$$
It is well known that, from this definition, if $x, y$ commute we have $e^xe^y=e^ye^x=e^{x+y}$.
Since real quaternions commute with all other quaternions, for $a \in \mathbb{R}$  we have $e^{a+z}=e^ae^z \; \forall z\in \mathbb{H}$ so, if $z=a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k} = a+\mathbf{v}$, we have $e^z=e^ae^\mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is an imaginary (or vector) quaternion.
Now we have:

**claim**

If $ \mathbf{v}  \in \mathbb{H}_P$ is an imaginary quaternion, putting $\theta=|\mathbf{v}|$  we have:
$$
e^\mathbf{v}= \cos\theta + \mathbf{v}\;\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta}
$$
**proof**

We note that:
$$
\mathbf{v}^2= (b \mathbf{i}+c  \mathbf{j} +d  \mathbf{k})(b \mathbf{i}+c  \mathbf{j} +d  \mathbf{k})=
-b^2-c^2-d^2=-|\mathbf{v}|^2
$$
so:
$$
 \mathbf{v}^2= -\theta^2 
\quad,\quad  \mathbf{v}^3= -\theta^2\mathbf{v} 
\quad,\quad \mathbf{v}^4= \theta^4 
\quad,\quad \mathbf{v}^5= \theta^4 \mathbf{v}
\quad,\quad \mathbf{v}^6= -\theta^6 
\quad,\quad \cdots 
$$
and the series become.
$$
\begin{split}
e^\mathbf{v}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{\mathbf{v}^k}{k!}=\\
%
&=1+\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{1!}-\dfrac{\theta^2}{2!}-\dfrac{\theta^2\mathbf{v}}{3!}+\dfrac{\theta^4}{4!}+\dfrac{\theta^4\mathbf{v}}{5!}-\dfrac{\theta^6}{6!}+\cdots=\\
%
&=1+\dfrac{\theta\mathbf{v}}{1!\,\theta}-\dfrac{\theta^2}{2!}-\dfrac{\theta^3\mathbf{v}}{3!\,\theta}+\dfrac{\theta^4}{4!}+\dfrac{\theta^5\mathbf{v}}{5!\,\theta}-\dfrac{\theta^6}{6!}+\cdots=\\
%
&=\left(1-\dfrac{\theta^2}{2!}+\dfrac{\theta^4}{4!}-\dfrac{\theta^6}{6!}\cdots\right)+\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{\theta}\left( \dfrac{\theta}{1!}-\dfrac{\theta^3}{3!}+\dfrac{\theta^5}{5!}\cdots\right)=\\
%
&=\cos\theta +\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{\theta}\sin\theta
\end{split}
$$

So the exponential of a quaternion is:
$$
e^z = e^{a+\mathbf{v}}=e^a \left(  \cos  |\mathbf{v}| +\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|} \,\sin |\mathbf{v}| \right)
$$

Comment: Does this have a link with the matrix exponential and quaternion representation in the form of a 2x2 complex matrix ?

Comment: Yes. It is special case because a pure imaginary quaternion is represented by a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ with null trace, and for such a matrix it is easy to show that $M^2=-|M|I$

Comment: Hi @EmilioNovati, in case $a = \cos \phi, \mathbf{v} = (\sin \phi) \mathbf{v_{\sin}}$ ($z$ is a unit quaternion, $\|\mathbf{v_{\sin}}\| = 1$), does $\sin |\mathbf{v}|$ means $\sin (\text{abs}(\sin \phi))$ or $\sin (\sin \phi)$? As far as I know $\phi \in [-\pi, \pi]$, that $\sin (\sin \phi)$ can be negative.

Comment: Since you had to multiply top and bottom by theta, sinc(x) is probably more accurate than sin(x)/x here just for clarity because it avoids the singularly of dividing by something with norm of zero.

Comment: @PineappleFish $\mathbf{v}$ goes to zero just as fast as $\sin|\mathbf{v}|$, so $\frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}$ handles the approach to the singularity just as well as $\mathrm{sinc}$ would. Since the actual numerator is quadratic, there isn't any numerical concern anyway. This leaves the singularity itself to take care of, and in a computer implementation you might want to call $\mathrm{sinc}$ (if provided) to avoid having to write `if (v == 0)` yourself. It's not very common though, as far as standard libraries neither C++ nor Python provide it (numpy has it though).

Answer (score 1):

If $q=\alpha+i\beta+j\gamma+k\delta$, it is always possible to represent $q$ as $q=a+Ib$, where $a=\alpha$, $b=\sqrt{\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2}$ and $I=\dfrac{i\beta+j\gamma+k\delta}{b}$. Note that $I^2=-1$. Since for complex numbers it holds $e^{a+ib}=e^a(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))$, the same holds for
$$
e^q=e^{a+Ib}=e^a(\cos(b)+I\sin(b))=e^a\left(cos\left(\sqrt{\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2}\right)+\dfrac{i\beta+j\gamma+k\delta}{\sqrt{\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2}}\sin\left(\sqrt{\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2}\right)\right).
$$