# How to convert a quaternion in polar form, back to rectangular form?

Tags: geometry, quaternions

After a lot of digging in google, I found [this](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.4377&rep=rep1&type=pdf)(eqn. 36, pg. 2849) paper, which gives a 'real' polar form of a quaternion. It states that, any quaternion q can be represented as $q=\vert{q}\vert{e^{i\phi'}e^{k\psi}e^{j\theta}}$ where phase $(\phi,\theta,\psi)$ is almost uniquely defined in the interval $[-\pi,\pi)\times[-\pi/2,\pi/2)\times[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$.

The formulas which they gave for getting those three phase angles were quite complex, and I'm wondering is there actually a way to convert a quaternion in polar form, back to rectangular form. If so, how?

Also, how to convert octonions to polar form?

Comment: So this comes down really to what $x_1, x_2, x_3$ you select for the Euler angles they define at the bottom of the page earlier

Comment: How do you visualize octonions in polar form anyway? There are many ways to parse the dimensions on a $7$-sphere.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is better to avoid Euler angles. If you know how the polar form of a quaternion is found starting from the rectangular form ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496308/how-can-i-express-a-quaternion-in-polar-form)), then you can reverse the process.
If we start with
$$q=\rho e^{\alpha \mathbf i+\beta \mathbf j +\gamma \mathbf k}=|q|e^{\mathbf v}$$
we can found $\sin \theta= \frac{|\mathbf v|}{|z|} $ and $\mathbf n=\frac{\mathbf v}{|\mathbf v|}$

so that:
$$q= \rho e^{\mathbf v}=\rho e^{\theta \mathbf n}=\rho(\cos \theta +\mathbf n \sin \theta) $$,

That is the rectangular form.

Comment: Is this transformation surjective and injective?