# How is the $\nabla^n $ operator defined?

Tags: operator-theory, vector-analysis, quantum-mechanics, differential-operators

In Quantum Mechanics, the [translation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)#Momentum_as_generator_of_translations) $\hat{T}$ can be written as

$$\hat{T}(\boldsymbol{x}) = 1 - \dfrac{ix\cdot \hat{p}}{\hbar} - \dfrac{i(x\cdot \hat{p})^2}{2\hbar^2} - \dfrac{i(x\cdot \hat{p})^3}{6\hbar^3} + \ldots$$
with
$$\hat{p} = -i\hbar \nabla $$
This question isn't really about the translation operator itself. I just wanted to mention it as an example. Something that is really bothering me in that Taylor expansion are the expressions
$$\hat{p}^n = (-i\hbar)^n \nabla^n$$
More specifically I wanted to ask what
$$\nabla^n $$
means? From what I know, $\nabla f = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f \\\partial_y f \\ \partial_z f\end{pmatrix}$ for a scalar function $f$. This makes sense. But then what is $\nabla^2 f$ supposed to be? From the kinetic energy operator I know that $\nabla^2 = \Delta$ should be the Laplacian-Operator. But this isn't how to product of two operator is defined. By the definition I should apply the nabla operator to $\nabla f = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f \\\partial_y f \\ \partial_z f\end{pmatrix}$ again:
$$\nabla \nabla f = \nabla \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f \\\partial_y f \\ \partial_z f\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f \\\partial_y f \\ \partial_z f\end{pmatrix}  \\\partial_y \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f \\\partial_y f \\ \partial_z f\end{pmatrix}  \\ \partial_z \begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f \\\partial_y f \\ \partial_z f\end{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}$$
which could probably be interpreted as the Jacobian  matrix.

Comment: The powers in the taylor expansion are multiplicative powers, not repeated applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, how do you define $p^n$ for classical $p$, or $\hat{p}^n$ for $\hat{p}$ with operator-valued components? It's that question you really need to answer; $\vec{\nabla}$ isn't the thorny part here. Indeed, we could instead write $\hat{p}_j=-i\hbar\partial_j$, so *all* the exponentiate-a-vector work is done elsewhere.

For a vector $\vec{v}$ we define $\vec{v}^2:=\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}=\sum_iv_i^2$, so $\vec{v}^0:=1,\,\vec{v}^1:=\vec{v},\,\vec{v}^{n+2}:=(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})\vec{v}^n$ defines all non-negative integer powers of $\vec{v}$ recursively, with $\vec{v}^{2n}=(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v})^n,\,\vec{v}^{2n+1}=\vec{v}^{2n}\vec{v}$. There's no problem using that with anything here, especially since $[\hat{p}_j,\,\hat{p}_k]=0$. [So $\nabla^2=\sum_j\partial_j^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

Comment: So, $\hat{p}^n$ is a scalar quantity for even powers and a vector quantity for odd powers?

Comment: @ook Yes. This also comes up when you exponentiate imaginary quaternions with a power series. (That's probably not of interest to you, but "Yes" was too short for a comment.)

Comment: But shouldn't all the terms in the expansion have the same dimension? Otherwise I wouldn't be able to add the terms together.

Comment: @ook $x\cdot p/\hbar$ is a dimensionless scalar.

Comment: What I mean is, the expansion would then consist of Scalar + Vector terms that can't be added together.

Comment: @ook As I've said, that's not true of $\hat{T}$. Which expansion are you talking about? If you're picking up on my comment about quaternions, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030737/exponential-function-of-quaternion-derivation).

Comment: No, I am still talking about $\hat{T}$. Well, I don't see why this isn't true for $\hat{T}$. The quantities $x$ and $\hbar$ are scalars, $\hat{p}$ is a vector, so the second term is a vector and it can't be added to the first Term, which is the scalar $1$. Similarly I get a scalar for the third term and again a vector for the fourth term.

Comment: @ook No, in this context $x$ means the  vector containing $x$, $y$ and $z$, and this is often called $r$. So $x\cdot p$ is a dot product, which is why I said it was a scalar.